# prime numbers and natural numbers

Tags: induction

Prove that $n^4+4^n$ is never prime. Here $n$ is any natural number greater than $1$.
I have tried by induction hypothesis but to no avail.
Can it be done by considering cases when $n$ is odd and when it is even?

Comment: When $n$ is even we already know it is not a prime. Tried binomial expansion with $n=2k+1$?

Comment: There's an intense feeling I've seen this before, but I can't locate a duplicate. Anyway, the case for odd $n$ can be proven by contradiction I believe.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: What do you mean by duplicate? The factorization generalizes to $n^4 + 4k^4$, but that doesn't do anything here because we already know the theorem when $n$ is even.

Comment: The question was answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166616/show-that-4n-n4-is-always-composite-forall-n-1/1166650#1166650) and earlier.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Sorry I didn't realize that what I said in my comment above does settle the problem as $4^{n-1}$ is indeed a fourth power when $n$ is odd...

Answer (score 5):

(1) If $n$ is odd, $n^4+4^n=(n^2+2^n-2^{n+1\over2}n)(n^2+2^n+2^{n+1\over2}n)$.

(2) If $n$ is even then $4|n^4+4^n$.

Comment: The only thing missing is to show that $n^2+2^n-2^{(n+1)/2}n\ne 1$ or equivalently that $n^4+4^n>n^2+2^n+2^{(n+1)/2}n$ which is easily seen by dividing through by $4^n$.

Answer (score 0):

on binomial expansion of (2k+1)^2,all terms are multiples of 4 but one term is 1.so 4 cannot be taken common.